# No console output on Win8 and later

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I have a WinForm project that also can be started as a console. The project's output type is Windows Application. To open the console and write text I have manually allocated the console and redirected the standard output, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604014/no-console-output-when-using-allocconsole-and-target-architecture-x86/43492087#43492087).

The console works with Win7 and Win2008R2, but not e.g. Win10. Nothing is written to screen, but listen to input from keyboard.

Is there any difference in how to setup standard output redirection on Win7 and Win>=8? How is standard output redirected on e.g. Win8?

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+F5?

Comment: why not change type to 'Console Application'? There will be the form and the console.

Comment: Crystal ball says that the real problem is that you are using VS2017.  The [proposed workaround](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/12166/console-output-is-gone-in-vs2017-works-fine-when-d.html) is good.