# log4net console appender logs viewing in .net core windows service application

Tags: .net-core, windows-services, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

Have anybody used console log4net appender in .net core based windows service application?
I am using .net core 2.1.6 console application which is hosted inside windows service. I have a file appender which is righting to file. wanted a console appender log view real time at console as well.

Answer (score 0):

A Windows Service has no visible console, it runs on an invisible desktop. See [Console.WriteLine() inside a Windows Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792978/console-writeline-inside-a-windows-service).

If you want to view your log in real-time, then open the log with a viewer that supports that, for example `tail -f` on Git Bash, or through Notepad++ with the tail button (eye icon). Note that the latter tends to hang of the file is being written to a lot.

Comment: I know windows service has no visible console. Is there Anyway i can forward my logs with any appender where i can view in any sort of console. like supervidor d in linux or anything else

Comment: I'm sure that for whatever log service you want to use, an appender is available.

Comment: I know about consoleappender / colourconsoleappender . Just not able to connect how can i show/watch those logs on windows service which is running a dotnet core application. i haven't used tail -f prior or notepad++ eye icon.I am use to notepad++ for my logs views. will try eye icon on it. Thanks